# How to deploy multiple containers on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, flask, heroku

I have created API(Flask RestFul) service, UI(in ReactJS) and Proxy service each having its own Dockerfile in their respective folder.

And there is Docker-compose.yaml file in main repository. It works locally on running following command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up`, but I am unable to find way to deploy multiple containers on heroku?

Here is my github repo: https://github.com/Darpan313/Flask-React-nginx-Docker-Compose

Comment: You need a `heroku.yml` file. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml